# Can pgadmin manage large objects?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is pgadmin aware of PostgreSQL large objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pgAdmin does not appear to have any *special* large object support.  You can however use the standard sql language functions available on any client interface to manage them.  See http://dave.webdev.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pg/largeobjects.html as a reference of these functions.

This leads to a number of important limitations.  You would get an escaped string when you pull a large object from the database.  You cannot, say, pull a file and display it as an image or the like.